# How to put the pieces together?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to use simple DIY robots, which only have wheels and IR receiver and emitters, to do distributed control algorithms for flocking and foraging. I went through tutorials for ROS, RViz, TF and URDF, yet I fail to understand how to put all the pieces together for a simulation.

Specifically, I know how to specify the robots in URDF, and after the Gazebo tutorial I'll know how to put a robot in a simulated physical world, but I'm not sure if I can put tens of robots in the same world. And more importantly, I don't know where does my algorithm for a single robot go, i.e. how do I code the behavior of a robot?

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164411/how-to-put-the-pieces-together?/) by [z.xing](https://answers.ros.org/users/17796/z.xing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-05-13**:
your question is so comprehensive that I cant answer . you should make your problem focusing on one point .

**Comment by [z.xing](https://answers.ros.org/users/17796/z.xing/) on 2014-05-13**:
If I hava a robot in a Gazebo world, what's the most common way to make the robot move autonomously, say running in a circle? Do I just simply publish robot states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you look for some tutorials in Gazebo about how to control a a robot with examples to fully understand how it works, then modify the tutorial codes to adapt them to your model. That would be the way I would do it.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0